# sudo cmd via ssh with expect twice consecutively

Tags: ssh, expect, sudo

I used `expect` to execute some command with sudo in remote host via ssh. The script lies as follow:

```
spawn ssh -q ${user}@${host}
expect "*?assword:"
send "${pass}\r"
expect "${user}@"
send "sudo ls\r"
expect "*?assword:"
send "${pass}\r"
expect "${user}@"
send "exit\r"
interac
```

It runs perfectly the first time, but when I executed it consecutively some error occurred. That's because `sudo` won't expire right away, so if sudo some command twice in a short time, the second maybe not need the password, thus the second `send "${pass}\r"` in above script failed!
  So how can we detect that and avoid sending password when sudo does not expire? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Modify the script so that expecting the sudo password is optional:

```
send "sudo ls\r"
expect {
    "*?assword:" {
        send "$pass\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "$user@" {
        send "exit\r"
    }
}
interac
```

Answer (score 2):

Clean the sudo authentication cache running `sudo -k` just after logging.